# Reading exchange email with mutt and davmail?

Tags: arch-linux, mutt, exchange, davmail

I must have read about 65 web pages about this issue, and tried them all, but so far I can't get it to work.

I can access my exchange email using Thunderbird, with the imap server set to `localhost` at port 1143, and the smtp server again set to `localhost`; this time with port 1025.  These port values are set in my davmail setup, and as I say this is what I use with Thunderbird.

The relevant portion of my `.muttrc` file is

```
set realname = 'Jim Bloggs'
set imap_user = 'AD\12345'
set imap_pass = 'My Password' 
set from = 'Jim.Bloggs@jimsmail.org'
# REMOTE FOLDERS
set folder = 'imap://12345@localhost:1143/Inbox'
set spoolfile ='imap://12345@localhost:1143/' 
set trash = 'imap://12345@localhost:1143/Trash'
# LOCAL FOLDERS FOR CACHED HEADERS AND CERTIFICATES
set header_cache =~/.mutt/jim_bloggs/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/jim_bloggs/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/jim_bloggs/certificates
# SMTP SETTINGS
set smtp_url = 'smtp://12345@localhost:1025/'
set ssl_starttls=yes
set smtp_pass = 'My Password' # use the same password as for IMAP
```

Currently what happen is this: it logs in and starts to download mail (and takes a v..e..r..y long time - about 15 or 20 minutes - to download 1902 headers), and then hangs on `Sorting mailbox...`

I am using mutt quite happily for accessing several gmail accounts, and I would like to use it to access my exchange mail as well.  But how...?

Comment: Back when I suffered under an Exchange mail server, I ended up using `fetchmail` to pull the mail down, and pointed `mutt` at the local mail files.

Comment: The point of using davmail is that it provides a local imap server - and it works fine with Thunderbird.  But for the life of me I can't get it to work with mutt!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to put this as a comment, because it's not really an answer but don't have enough reputation. Anyway, I just ran into the same issue (reported to neomutt as [issue #186](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/186#issuecomment-252442647) and after much debugging found that davmail seems to access all the mail in every folder when mutt checks the mailbox stats (which is obviously horribly slow). A workaround which is not really satisfying is to `set imap_check_subscribed=no` and not put many (or any) mailboxes in your config.

Comment: Nah, it is a decent workaround in my opinion.  At best it explains what it happens.